Gremlin Complete Hierarchy From a Specific Node
I am having difficult time to fetch the completely hierarchy by a node id.
I want the all children and sub children which are directly and in-directly connected to a particular node.
Node Properties: (~id, 'entity_name', 'entity_type', ~label)
Edge Properties: (~id, ~label, 'journey_id')
graph_result = g.V(entity_id).repeat(inE().outV().dedup()).emit().path().toList()

for path in graph_result:
    for item in path:
        if type(item) == Edge:
            if (item.outV.id, item.inV.id) not in unique_ids:
                unique_ids.add((item.outV.id, item.inV.id))
                results.append({
                    "src_entity_id": item.outV.id,
                    "src_entity_name": item.outV.label,
                    "target_entity_id" : item.inV.id,
                    "target_entity_name" : item.inV.label,
                    "association": item.label
                })

Using Above code I am able to get the hierarchy, Since I am deduplication the node vertex, I am not getting excepted result. I want to dedup based on the (outV.id, inV.id, label) combination of these three.
or is there a better way to do it?

This sounds more like you're wanting to get all of the edges in the hierarchy then, and not necessarily the vertices.  If that is the case, you can do something like:
g.V(entity_id).
    repeat(
        outE().
        aggregate('edges').
        inV().
        dedup()
    ).
    cap('edges').
    unfold().
    elementMap()

And then the elementMap will contain the inV, outV, and label for all of the edges.
Better yet, you can project off of each unique edge to get what you're looking for:
g.V(entity_id).
    repeat(
        outE().
        aggregate('edges').
        inV().
        dedup()
    ).
    cap('edges').
    unfold().
    project('srcid','srcname','destid','destname','association').
        by(outV().id()).
        by(outV().label()).
        by(inV().id()).
        by(inV().label()).
        by(label())


I have modified the first query like:
g.V(entity_id).
repeat(
inE().
aggregate('edges').
outV().
dedup()
).
cap('edges').
unfold().
elementMap().toList()
I am getting timeout now.

and for second query while running from python getting error
TypeError: 'GraphTraversal' object is not callable.
line: .by(outV().id())

You may need to use the anonymous traversal on each of the calls within the by() steps.  from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __ and then use as __.outV().id().

I tried same issue, I am using gremlinpython v3.7.2.

I made it work
(
g.V(entity_id)
.repeat(inE().aggregagte('edges').outV().dedup())
.cap("edges")
.unfold()
.project("to", "label", "from")
.by(outV())
.by(label())
.by(inV())
.dedup()
.toList()
)
instead of fetching the id in the step, I am fetching the vertex and getting id later while iterating over it using python. It is working but the problem is it's very slow.
is there any better way?

What database engine are you using?  For the time being, can you add profile() to the end of the query and run it and show the results here?

I am using AWS Neptune.
Profile Result Link

That's a decently large operation to ask of an OLTP engine - the profile is showing ~2.5M results being processed by the repeat() step.  What you're basically executing in this query is a Weakly Connected Components algorithm.  You may want to investigate using Neptune Analytics for this instead: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune-analytics/latest/userguide/wcc.html
